# Transmission not shifting from park

Tags: transmission, nissan, maxima

I own a Nissan Maxima 2000.  Over the past 2 or 3 days I am observing a strange problem with my transmission. Once I start the vehicle, I place my foot on the brake and try to engage drive, the shift handle doesn't move. I know when pressing the brake pedal its supposed to give a signal to the transmission whether its safe to engage or not.  I was not able to hear the click sound even though I pressed very hard on the brake pedal.

Please help, if there is anything else here on the board.  I do not want to spend a large amount of cash to resolve the issue.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't move", do you mean you are able to move the shift lever and the car doesn't move, or that you cannot move the shift lever itself?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the brake switch is on its way out. This is essentially a solenoid switch which is supposed to disengage the lock on your shifter when you press the brake pedal.

If your Maxima has enough in common with the models I know, there should be a button labeled 'Transmission Lock' next to the shifter that you can press to manually release the lock.

The release may be hidden under a small plastic cover. With a small flat blade screwdriver remove the small cover. Insert the screwdriver in the hole to release the shifter lock. Beware that the brake lights may not work. It may be worth checking for a blown fuse

[image: Shifter Lock Release]

Comment: The release may be hidden under a small plastic cover. With a small flat blade screwdriver remove the small cover. Insert the screwdriver in the hole to release the shifter lock. Beware that the brake lights may not work. It may be worth checking  for a blown fuse.